# ConstraintSet: Listview won't move properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

No Matter what i write inside of Constraintset.connect to change the position, it always just stays where it is (i want it to move from outside the screen into the screen from the left side), at the moment the view is fully inside of the screen and only the left constraint is missing).
Thanks.

ListviewItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#202020">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listItemImageView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listItemImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/listItemImageView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/listItemImageView"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="This Text will change"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/listItemImageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/listItemImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/urlayout"
    tools:context="com.example.me.gesturelaunchertest.MainActivity">
    <!-- Ab fadeduration sachen für I usw. -->
    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gesOverlay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
        android:fadeDuration="300"
        android:gestureStrokeAngleThreshold="0"
        android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="300.0"
        android:gestureStrokeSquarenessThreshold="0"
        android:gestureColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gestureStrokeWidth="40.0"
        android:uncertainGestureColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/applistview"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout);
            constraintSet=new ConstraintSet();

            constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

            constraintSet.connect(applistview.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 110);

            constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with `ConstraintSet.LEFT` and `ConstraintSet.RIGHT` not working. See [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62154545) on the bug tracker.

Try using `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` instead:

```
constraintSet.connect(applistview.getId(), ConstraintSet.START,
        constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, 110);
```

I hope this helps.